# Jetpack Compose shadow over LazyColumn

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to draw this shadow below list header, to give an illusion of `LazyColumn` items scrolling below (or behind) the header: [image: shadow]

I tried:

1. using `Modifier.shadow()` but it does not yield desired result.
2. drawing a `Box` with gradient background, which does what I want, but get overdrawn with `LazyColumn` elements.

To counter this drawing over my gradient I tried the following:

1. putting `Box` after `LazyColumn`,
2. setting `Modifier.zIndex(10f)` to `Box`.

Of course, none of that worked. Immediately after `LazyColumn` elements were drawn, gradient disappeared.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried a Surface with elevation?

From docs
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material#elevation-overlays

```
Surface(
    elevation = 2.dp,
    color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface, // color will be adjusted for elevation
    /*...*/
) { 

// TODO - Put your list header here.

 }
```

Comment: Using `Surface` introduced some other issue, but I managed to get around it. That being said, shadow is not quite as the designer wants it. Until better solution is found, I'll accept your answer.